# Django 1.4 and django-compressor strangeness

Tags: python, django, django-compressor

I use `django-compressor 1.1.2` with `Django 1.4` when using `compress` templatetags `PROJECT_PATH` appended to `STATIC_URL` after compression

```
/static/Users/sultan/.virtualenvs/mediabox/somedia/somedia/public/media/media-cache/compressor/css/1d7cd4216904.css
```

When I don't set 
    COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR = os.path.join(MEDIA_CACHE, 'compressor')

Output looks like

```
/static/CACHE/css/1d7cd4216904.css
```

**settings**

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    ...
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder'
)

COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR = os.path.join(MEDIA_CACHE, 'compressor')
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

Thanks,

Sultan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the doc](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR)

```
django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR 
Default :   'CACHE' 
Controls the directory inside COMPRESS_ROOT that compressed files will be written to.)
```

I don't know what's your `MEDIA_CACHE` setting here, but you don't need to join directories to generate `COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR`, just give it a relative name such as `'compressor'` or `'cache'` to try.